# Redirect from an MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Does anyone know the syntax for a redirect from a view to another view?

I mean, I need to add the redirect code in the actual view, not the controller.

Comment: I know I should be doing it in the controller but I need to know how is it done in the View

Comment: an anchor? <a href="/otherView">Go to other view</a>

Comment: do you mean a link within the view?

Comment: not a link - I want the view to automatically redirect to another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically redirect, you can use

1. Javascript:

   `window.location.href="otherView";`
2. [Meta Refresh](http://www.hicom.net/~oedipus/wai/ua/tests/redirect_test.html)

   `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="N;URL=http://www.foo.com/YourView">`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this directly in the view with MVC code. The view handles the display of a page only, and is only reached in the code once the final destination of a request has been determined. You can do this however with both JavaScript and HTML:

JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

**This method is discouraged by the W3C and should not be used. I have only included it here for informational purposes.**

All  that said, you should never have to do this. If you are trying to implement this in your MVC site then you are not respecting the MVC pattern and should rethink your architecture.

Comment: so there's no way at all to do it without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this via javascript

```
    $(function(){
         window.location.href = "www.yournewUrl.com";
});
```

or

```
        $(function(){
             window.location.href = "@Html.ActionLink("linkie, "action", "controller")" 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; ,URL=http://whatev.com/dd.html">
```

but it is [not recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724055%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)